# Центрирование изображения по центру блока

Tags: css, css3

Как в `css` можно разместить изображение так, чтобы при любом размере (даже в ситуациях, когда оно более блока, в который вложено), центр этого изображения совпадал с центром блока?

Устанавливать изображение в качестве фона нельзя, так как есть элементы, выходящие за пределы блока, в который оно вложено, и они не должны обрезаться.

Comment: Поместить его в фон?

Comment: `background: url(..путь к изображению) no-repeat 50% 50%`

Comment: @quertiy В фон помещать нельзя, так как есть элементы, выходящие за пределы блока, в который вложено изображение, и в этом случае они будут обрезаться.

Answer (score 1):

Если решение с фоновой картинкой не подходит, а нужно позиционировать именно изображение  внутри контейнера, то можно поступить так:

```
<style>
    .container {
        width: 300px;
        height: 1700px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        outline: solid 1px;
    }

    img {
        position: absolute;
        top: calc(50% - 500px);
        left: calc(50% - 500px);
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <img src="https://worldarchery.org/sites/default/files/imce/images/target_recurve.png" alt="">
</div>
```

500px - половина высоты и ширины изображения.

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуй добавлю еще один ответ.Есть специальное свойство, которое работает как `backgroud-size: cover`, в случае когда картинка задана фоном. Единственный минус в поддержке браузерами. http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://ak-hdl.buzzfed.com/static/enhanced/webdr05/2013/9/17/5/enhanced-buzz-1492-1379411828-15.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: поддержка не очень хорошая - http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit хотя  неплохое свойство

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border:1px solid #000;
}

img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://ak-hdl.buzzfed.com/static/enhanced/webdr05/2013/9/17/5/enhanced-buzz-1492-1379411828-15.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Никто не предлагает `display: flex` Печально. А ведь, 2017 год на носу.

```
.img_wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.img_wrapper img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Для `<div class="img_wrapper"><img ... /></div>`

Comment: такой вариант масштабирует изображение если оно больше чем .img_wrapper

Comment: @Влад да. Изображение не может быть шире 100% ширины родительского блока или выше 100% его высоты. Пропорции изображения сохраняются